# CORS issue when fetching PDF from Firebase Storage in Flutter web after deployment

Tags: flutter, firebase, cors

I'm working on a Flutter web application where I'm trying to fetch a PDF file from Firebase Storage using the SfPdfViewer widget. Strangely, everything works perfectly in my local development environment. However, after deploying to Firebase, I'm encountering a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) issue.

```
class PdfViewAtom extends StatefulWidget {
   final url;

  const PdfViewAtom({super.key, this.url});

  @override
  State<PdfViewAtom> createState() => _PdfViewAtomState();
}

 class _PdfViewAtomState extends State<PdfViewAtom> {
    final GlobalKey<SfPdfViewerState> _pdfViewerKey = GlobalKey();

     Uint8List? pdfBytes;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  // Fetch PDF file from Firebase Storage URL
    _fetchPdf();
   }

Future<void> _fetchPdf() async {
  final Uri pdfUrl = Uri.parse(widget.url);

  final response = await http.get(
    pdfUrl,
   );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    pdfBytes = Uint8List.fromList(response.bodyBytes);
    setState(() {});
   } else {
    print('Failed to fetch PDF: ${response.statusCode}');
  }
  }
  


  PdfViewerController? con = PdfViewerController();
  @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 2.5;
     return Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
         color: Colors.white70,
         height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
         width: width, // Adjust height as needed
         child: pdfBytes != null
              ? SfPdfViewer.memory(pdfBytes!)
              : const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
     )}}
```

**console showing**

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/datasciencesell.appspot.com/o/hh.pdf?alt=media&token=684f07ff-cd0d-4b2d-b29c-431bf34e2744' from origin 'https://datasciencesell.web.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

**this is the firebase.json**

```
{
  "hosting": {
  "source": ".",
  "ignore": [
  "firebase.json",
  "**/.*",
  "**/node_modules/**"
 ],

 "frameworksBackend": {
   "region": "asia-east1"
  }
 }
}
```